# Converting MS Access Conditional Formatting for SQL Backend

Tags: ms-access, vba, conditional-formatting

We have recently used SQL Server Migration Asssistant for Access (SSMA) to convert our Access tables into SQL.

This included converting the Access style dates into Datetime fields.

Our VB developer now says that the conditional formatting no longer works.

The code is as follows

```
If Me.Expiry - Date < 366 Then Me.Expiry.BackColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)   
--if date is within 1 year = red
```

Using the new sql tables, I'm not entirely sure how we could convert this.

Could we still use an `IF` but add in say `greater than GetDate() but less than 
DATEADD(day, 366, GetDate())`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my VB knowledge is extremely limited.

Comment: If your VB developer says conditional formatting no longer works, perhaps he should ask about it. Conditional formatting uses Access expressions and is independent of the SQL dialect used by the backend. Conditional formatting should not be affected by migrating a local table to SQL server, unless you've migrated it in such a way that Access no longer understands the format of a column (e.g. migrating dates to DateTime2 then using the ancient {SQL Server} ODBC driver that has no support for DateTime2 fields).

Comment: Your suggestions are T-SQL, not VBA. If you have converted the date field to _DateTime2_ in SQL Server, only the newest _Native SQL Server ODBC driver_ will read it correctly. The old _SQL Server_ driver will read it as text. If you have to use the old driver, use _DateTime_ in SQL Server.

Comment: Many thanks for these suggestions, I agree that this should be the job of the developer to ask but I just wanted to make sure that this wasn't a SQL issue.  I really appreciate your advice.